# Application of "smoothing" (mollifying) to a PDE problem?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

So I briefly heard a presentation on applying smoothing (or "mollifying") to the following problem:

$u$ continuous in $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

And suppose $$\int_{\Omega} u \psi dx = 0$$

for all $\psi \in C_0^{\infty}(\Omega)$

Show that $u(x)=0$ for all $x \in \Omega$

---

Anyone could clarify how the smoothing works out in this and what is it about (hearing about it the first time).

Comment: What do you mean by smoothing?

Comment: @mcd I believe it's about approximating the integral area using simpler smooth functions.

Comment: I'm probably talking about mollification (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245174/constructing-a-sequence-of-test-functions-whose-convergence-is-uniform).

Comment: If $u$ is continuous, then you don't need an approximation argument; continuity of $u$ is sufficient to conclude that $u = 0$ in $\Omega$.

Comment: @Mike Is it? What if $u$ is continuous, but varies so that the integral still equals $0$, but $u$ is not a constant?

Answer (score 1):

As I already mentioned in my comment: if $u$ is continuous in $\Omega$ and 
\begin{equation}
\int_{\Omega} u \psi = 0
\end{equation}
for all $\psi \in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$, then $u$ vanishes identically in $\Omega$.

Let's prove my claim (via contradiction): Suppose $u$ does not vanish identically in $\Omega$, i.e., there exists a point $x_0 \in \Omega$ such that $u(x_0) > 0$ or $u(x_0) < 0$. Without loss of generality, we may assume that $u(x_0)= \delta>0$. Since $u$ is continuous, we find a radius $R = R(x_0) > 0$ such that $u(y) \geq \delta /2> 0$ for all $y \in B_R(x_0)$, where $B_R(x_0)$ denotes the open ball of radius $R$ around $x_0$. Now, choose $r \in (0 , R)$ and let $\psi \in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$ be a cut-off function on $B_r(x_0)$; that is, $\psi \geq 0$, $\psi = 1$ in $B_r(x_0)$, and $\text{supp} \, \psi \subset B_R(x_0)$. We then find that
\begin{equation}
0 = \int_{\Omega} u \psi = \int_{B_R(x_0)} u \psi = \int_{B_r(x_0)} u + \int_{B_R(x_0) \setminus B_r(x_0)} u \psi \geq \int_{B_r(x_0)} u \geq \frac{\delta}{2} \lvert B_r(x_0)\rvert > 0\, .
\end{equation}
This, however, is impossible, and hence we do not find a point $x_0 \in \Omega$ such that $u(x_0) > 0$. By a similar argument, we also find no point $x_0 \in \Omega$ such that $u(x_0) < 0$. So $u$ vanishes identically in $\Omega$.

By the way, if $u$ is not continuous but only $L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$, then the statement is also true. In this case, however, you need to approximate $u$ by continuous functions.

Comment: Where do you apply "smoothing" or mollifying?

Comment: I do not use mollification if $u$ is continuous. For $u \in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$, we define $u_{\varepsilon} = u * \rho_{\varepsilon}$, where $\rho_{\varepsilon}$ is the standard mollifier. You then know that the statement holds for all $u_{\varepsilon}$ (since they are continuous) and $u_{\varepsilon} \to u$ in $L^1(\Omega)$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$. This proves the claim for $u$.